# Restrict the response body that gets returned from Spring Boot Filter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am using `spring boot-2.1.6`, I have declared a filter that does basic authentication ops before the call actually reaches the controller. The problem is that when I throw an exception from the filter (in case the call is unauthorized) it leads to a 500 error code and an entire stacktrace being printed out in the body of the response. How can I modify what happens or rather what response to send when that exception is thrown

I tried `@ControllerAdvice` but I soon found out that it's basically for when the call reaches the controller and then that throws an exception. And for filters it wouldn't work.

How can I handle errors thrown from Filters to a valid and a more developer friendly response?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

Comment: @daniu Yeah I've tried this. This doesn't work for filters

Answer (score 1):

You could catch that exception and throw as a error response in filter.

```java
@Component
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        try {
            if(basicAuthenticationFails) { // Your Authentication Logic
                throw new UnAuthorizedException("Error while processing");
            }
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (UnAuthorizedException e) { // Create a custom exception for this.
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), "UnAuthorized);
        }
    }
}
```

This will return a json like below,

```
{
   "timestamp":"2019-07-08T05:47:34.870+0000",
   "status":401,
   "error":"Unauthorized",
   "message":"UnAuthorized",
   "path":"/foo"
}
```

you could also send error by creating a `class`,

```
try {
// Logic
} catch (UnAuthorizedException e) {
   ((HttpServletResponse) response).setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY.value());
   response.getWriter().write(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new ErrorResponse(e.getMessage())));
}
```